# Is it possible to create miyawaki fruit tree forest?

Tags: fruit-trees

Can you help me with the [miyawaki](http://siruthuli.com/miyawaki-method-of-creating-forest/) method of fruit tree forest?
In the internet, I couldn't get complete details about the method.

Comment: This looks off topic. We don't cover forests here.

Comment: Please provide more details about the site you intend to reforest such as size, location, current use, soil type, your budget or look here https://www.google.ca/search?q=miyawaki+method

Comment: Is it not about creating real forest, but more like creating a forest-like area in a garden, so I think it is on-topic (even though it is not for every garden).

Comment: Who knows? The question is lacking in details so you need to impose your own assumptions.

Comment: Hi yogece!  Are you trying to use this method in your yard? We need more details, like what @kevinsky asked for, and also a picture, or this may be [closed](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).  My internet search shows it as very specialized and difficult, usually used by professionals, pre-planned for a long time, and not usually in people's yards.  I'm not saying it can't be done, just that we need more information in order for our tree people (sorry, I'm not one of them) to know what to tell you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My opinion the miyawagani...thing is it is just another 'trend'.  Plants love being planted together but planting 11 different trees in a PIT?  To make an au naturale forest?

Do you expect to enjoy this forest?  Forests make themselves over thousands of years. What we humans need to do is stop using up forest ecosystems because those ecosystems take thousands of years to create, test themselves, adapt, change and stabilize.  Once we cut them down, they are gone forever unless we allow a few thousand years of non intervention by us humans.  Then they come back. Unless there is a major catastrophic change to the elements in the environment those same trees and shrubs and grasses will come back...in a succession.

Do you know what your tree/shrub association is for your area?  For instance, mine is Lodgepole succession to Ponderosa Pine and Bitterbrush.  This area has had volcanoes, then fire, now in a succession forest that is Jack and Lodgepole Pine and Bitterbrush and someday to once again be a Ponderosa Pine forest with Manzanita.

You most certainly could create a 'forest' with privacy, shade, fragrance, edibles, that once you managed to get your trees and plants (indigenous) matured could be fairly maintenance free and usable by you.

If you could explain what it is you are trying to achieve it would be very helpful.  Forests are nice but nature does a better job than we could imagine or should even attempt to do.

What type of forest do you have in mind?  I would most certainly not worry about that pit planting stuff.  Honest.

Comment: Is your answer that you shouldn't do it because you disagree with the methodology?

Comment: I do not even understand the GOAL of this forestingthingy.  If we leave areas alone, then they will revert to the original forest type environment that had evolved with no help necessary nor beneficial by humans.  I would never plant any plant in a 'bowl' carved out of the ground.  I could not imagine planting 11 different species in that tiny bowl, much less think I could dictate a forest type or species that would be better than what the area is already slated for by nature.  Yeah, the methodology in my opinion is just wrong.

Comment: So, I guess you'll never be receptive to any new ideas that conflict with your old ones.

Comment: There are just basic principles that have to be met in order to have success with plants.  This is akin to reinventing the wheel. The basics are tried and true and tested and really work.  The basics are tough enough to understand and then these 'Trend' type ideas come up that go against the basics?  I can see the drainage issues right away, a bowl for baby trees?  I'd like to see the list of 11 different species that could or should be planted together.  Gardening is a lot of work which needs some success shown to be continued...

Comment: And success makes gardeners.  Gardeners that will teach the correct basics to others instead of passing on the old wive's tales that do not never did never will work.  If I am resistant to 'new idea's' it would be because I've never seen a new idea yet that worked better than good old basics.